# Thriller/horror book about someone whose soul had taken several people's bodies in order to survive/escape (?)

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror

Please, help me with the title of a book. I read it a few months ago and it's quite new, I think. It's something between a thriller and a horror. I remember very little details and I'm not sure they're correct:

Two young people are staying in an old house (?) on a vast property (something like in the middle of a forest?). A third one comes and stays with them for a while, then disappears. After a while, you find out that the third one had been murdered and one of the two had taken his body. I think the one whose body had been killed and thrown in a hole or something like that, had taken the girl's body (basically, his body and her soul had been "disposed"). After switching a few bodies, in the end there is a last confrontation between two women and you believe the nice one survives, only to find out that the soul who had taken several bodies managed to enter her body, too, and escape.

Comment: I don't recognize the book, but it sounds like the same premise as the movie "Fallen" (1998) with Denzel Washington. A Demon can jump from body to body simply by touch. (but the person possessed does not know it while possessed, nor realize it when the Demon has left) While possessing someone, the Demon is killing random people. You might look for books similar to the movie "Fallen"

Comment: Thank you! I found it! I was "Behind Her Eyes". :)

Comment: :) You can still post your own answer if you wish, or accept the current CW answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Per the OP's comment above, this was "[Behind Her Eyes](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28965131-behind-her-eyes)" by Sarah Pinborough.

> Louise is a single mom, a secretary, stuck in a modern-day rut. On a rare night out, she meets a man in a bar and sparks fly. Though he leaves after they kiss, she’s thrilled she finally connected with someone.
>
> When Louise arrives at work on Monday, she meets her new boss, David. The man from the bar. The very married man from the bar…who says the kiss was a terrible mistake but who still can’t keep his eyes off Louise.
>
> And then Louise bumps into Adele, who’s new to town and in need of a friend, but she also just happens to be married to David. David and Adele look like the picture-perfect husband and wife, but then why is David so controlling, and why is Adele so scared of him?
>
> As Louise is drawn into David and Adele’s orbit, she uncovers more puzzling questions than answers. The only thing that is crystal clear is that something in this marriage is very, very wrong, but Louise can’t guess how wrong―and how far a person might go to protect their marriage’s secrets.

The Goodreads reviews frequently reference the ending (which basically matches your summary) with varying degrees of "this was brilliant" and "I feel cheated by the ending". You can find a spoiler review [here](https://www.marieclaire.com/culture/a35537409/behind-her-eyes-ending-explained/).

> Louise tries to help David flee from Rob-Adele's clutches. She also digs into Rob's history, calling Rob's sister who confirms Rob was never to be seen again, confirming Louise's suspicions that Rob is dead. But before any of this can really come to a head, Rob-Adele tricks Louise into coming to her home by pretending she is committing suicide. Rob-Adele then sets fire to her own beautiful townhouse. Louise comes to Rob-Adele's home only to realize she can't break in to help; she decides to try astral projecting inside to save Rob-Adele. Rob-Adele seizes this opportunity to switch bodies with Louise, becoming Rob-Louise. Rob-Louise then actually overdoses Adele's body so that Adele-Louise dies. Rob-Louise then pulls Adele's body from the burning home so that she looks like a hero who tried, but failed, to save her friend.

Answer (score 0):

Might you be thinking of Emma Bull's [*Bone Dance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_Dance) about a small cadre of body-hopping 'riders' and what happens when these beings start hunting one another?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you might be thinking of one of Octavia Butler's novels in the *Patternmaster* cycle, for example [*Mind of My Mind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_of_My_Mind) where telepathic humans exist within wider human society, but the more powerful are able to possess the bodies of other telepaths (and thereby displace or destroy the original personality).

[image: Mind of My Mind paperback cover] [image: Mind of My Mind paperback cover] [image: Mind of My Mind paperback cover]